# Update Contact in Journey Builder canvas

Tags: field-update, dataextensions, journeybuilder

We want to update contact in our Journey. The data extension A enters the journey and it has "UNIQ_ID" column linked to Contact Key in Data designer. In the journey, we want to update "Flag" column in data extension B. Data extesnion B also has "UNIQ_ID".

Should Data extension A and data extension B be linked by "UNIQ_ID" in Data designer for this? 
Is there anything else we need to do ?
I have set "record Date" field in data extension B to "Current date" to capture record date. Will it update everytime we update the contact ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create a 1:1 cardinal relationship linking the `UNIQ_ID` field from DE A to the same field in DE B. Note that DE A should be mapped to the Contact Record, so your Attribute Group would look like:

**Contact Record** <- `link to Contact Key` -> **DE A** <- `link to UNIQ_ID` -> **DE B**

No the record date won't update with the Date. The current date feature that you refer to is just used when a record is created. There is no method to insert the current date using an Update Contact Data Activity at this time.